# how to solve system.OutOfMemoryException error in vb.net?

Tags: json, memory, out-of-memory

i am totally stuck with this error, please do help me..

i create a json file, user can select from start date to end date..
so button1 function as to generate the file..
the program goes well until i select a larger data to generate.. then this memory error comes out.. Here is my code:

```html
  Using writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
                With writer
                    .WriteStartObject()
                    .WritePropertyName("LiveValue")
                    .WriteStartArray()
                    Do



                      
                        liveValue.Time_Stamp = u
                        liveValue.Current = Generator.Next(MyMin_Current, MyMax_Current + 1)
                        liveValue.Voltage = Generator.Next(MyMin_Voltage, MyMax_Voltage + 1)
                        liveValue.Power = liveValue.Current * liveValue.Voltage

                        .WriteStartObject()
                        .WritePropertyName("ID")
                        .WriteValue(i)
                        .WritePropertyName("TimeStamp")
                        .WriteValue(liveValue.Time_Stamp)
                        .WritePropertyName("MotorID")
                        .WriteValue(liveValue.MotorID)
                        .WritePropertyName("Current")
                        .WriteValue(liveValue.Current)
                        .WritePropertyName("Voltage")
                        .WriteValue(liveValue.Voltage)
                        .WritePropertyName("Power")
                        .WriteValue(liveValue.Power)

                        .WriteEndObject()

                        i = i + 1

                        If liveValue.MotorID < 20 Then
                            liveValue.MotorID = liveValue.MotorID + 1
                        Else
                            liveValue.MotorID = 1
                        End If


                        'If endTime > startTime Then
                        '    liveV.Time_Stamp = u.AddMinutes(+1)
                        'Else
                        '    liveV.Time_Stamp = endTime
                        'End If

                        '(Time Stamp) Time changed every 7secs
                        If i = w Then
                            u = u.AddMinutes(+1)
                            w = w + 20
                        End If

                    Loop Until (liveValue.Time_Stamp = endTime)
                    .WriteEndArray()
                    .WriteEnd()






                End With
                file1.WriteLine(sb.ToString)
                pBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous
               


            End Using
```

please do help me to solve it..Thank you